# Responsive images, fitting inside parent

Tags: css, responsive

Looking for CSS-only solution for images to scale while retaining their aspect ratio but fit inside the parent container. Images should never stretch outside of the parent.

Refer to demo, the first two work, while the last one is skewing it's width incorrectly.

https://jsfiddle.net/louiswalch/os6ehsjx/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <p>Exact</p>
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"/>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>Fit to width</p>
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x200/000/fff"/>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>Fit to height</p>
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x600/000/fff"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  background-color: pink;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 66.6%; /* (H/W) * 100 */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.container IMG {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.container P {
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While impatiently waiting for the CSS property [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) to be implemented by all major browser vendors....

Instead of `img` use a `div`

```
<div class="bg" style="background-image: url('//placehold.it/800x600');"></div>
```

then in CSS:

```
.bg{
   position:absolute;
   top:0; left:0; right:0; buttom:0;
   background: none 50%;
   background-size: contain;    /* ur use: cover  to cover the entire space*/
}
```

Comment: I am hoping to be able to do this and still keep IMG. Possible?

Comment: Yep, can't do what the OP wants without scripting (if he wants an img tag exclusively).

Comment: pretty sure he wants `contain` instead of `cover`

Comment: @LouisW you can push the images away using some negative offset. Or you can use JS to dynamically replace the `img.src` with a transparent base64 pixel, and set the image background-image to the old src..

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use. I put an image into the background of an base64 image(so it validates).

```
<img class="thumb" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" style="background-image: url('http://your.com/image.jpg')">
```

And here is the css

```
.thumb{
width:345px;
height:260px;
background:center;
background-size:cover;   
}
```

Comment: Than rather use a `div`. An image with no `alt=""` and even more a `src` that has a 1x1 base64 pixel... I'm almost sure it's bad for both SEO and validation.